# Conversion from Byte Array to hex format using bitcoinjs-min.js

Tags: javascript, bitcoin

I'm trying to generate the public key from the following x and y of  object Q in the browser. The problem is in order to use this public key for verifying a JWT I have to get the hexadecimal format of the key. I'm using keypair from the src="bitcoinjs.min.js" which does not allow me to retrieve the hexadecimal form of public key.
Is there any library or function to convert it into hexadecimal form?

```
// Taking reference from http://procbits.com/2013/08/27/generating-a-bitcoin-address-with-javascript
var pubX = hdnode.keyPair.Q.x.toByteArrayUnsigned();
var pubY = hdnode.keyPair.Q.y.toByteArrayUnsigned();
var publicKeyBytes = pubX.concat(pubY);
publicKeyBytes.unshift(0x04);
```

meanwhile I tried

```
<script src="http://peterolson.github.com/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js"></script>
var publicKeyInt = BigInt.fromByteArrayUnsigned(publicKeyBytes);
```

but it's not working
Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you have a byte stream it's pretty easy to print out the hex equiv.
do something like (using String.fromCharCode) `var lower = byte & 0x0f; console.log(String.fromCharCode(lower > 0x09 ? lower + 55 : lower + 48)); var upper = byte >> 4; /* rinse and repeat */`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WORKING: 
below is the piece of working code which is taking a byte array and gives out a hexadecimal string.

```
function toHexString(bytes) {
  return bytes.map(function(byte) {
    return (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)
  }).join('')
}
```

Thanks @derekdreery for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I'm going to expand on my comment

Assume: key is an array or an iterable of bytes

```
function getHexArray(key) {
    function num2hex(num) {
        return num > 9 ? num + 55 : num + 48;
    }
    var hex_key = [];
    var lower, upper;
    for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        lower = key[i] & 0x0f;
        upper = key[i] >> 4;
        return String.fromCharCode(num2hex(upper)) + 
            String.fromCharCode(num2hex(lower));
    }
    return hex_key;
}
```

Note that if you want a long string of hex, you probably want to reverse the order of lower and upper (this is for writing as an array of hex bytes)

This function allows you to put in an array of bytes and will output an array of 2-char strings representing the hex value of the bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I have an array in the form 
`4,-101,122,-41,-30,23,-28,3,-16,61,-112,-119,44,115,-76,-121,50,-84,106,88,89,80,9,45,-61,-40,-104,-125,21,-61,-79,123,-76,-85,-92,62,41,-94,91,64,112,-107,106,-38,-37,73,0,-54,60,26,-62,46,-78,-106,-81,-82,-57,87,50,85,89,-18,-70,75,-1`


After using the above function I'm just getting `04`
Is this the right byte array which is expected by the function you have proposed